# taxis in Rust, Germany

Tags: germany, taxis

Is it easily possible to find an early morning taxi from Rust, Germany / near Europa Park? If I want to take a train from Ringsheim at around 8.20 am, can I make it in time?

Is there a recommended taxi app that I should use to book the taxi? Or should I contact some local taxi office a day before?

Is there any bus from Rust to Ringsheim? We will be 5 people. 3 adults, 2 kids.

Comment: If you decide to use a taxi I suggest: book the day before, tell them how many passengers (a sedan/saloon might not take 5), how much luggage and the time of the train you want to catch. They will advise what time the taxi should be booked for. Any decent taxi operation will be working 24/7.

Comment: Are you staying in one of the Europa-Park hotels or another hotel in Rust, by any chance? If yes, then you can also ask the front desk, they should be quite familiar with taxi operations. If you stay in a private apartment, check my answer for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For buses and trains in Baden-Württemberg, go to
[bwegt.de](https://www.bwegt.de/ihr-nahverkehr/reiseinformationen/fahrplanauskunft) (site name is a pun on BW=Baden-Württemberg and bewegt=moved) and enter your travel details, e.g. "Rust Europapark" and "Ringsheim Bahnhof". Unfortunately, the site seems to be in German only.

With the results, you will also get a map of other bus stops in the area, so you might find a stop that is more convenient for you. E.g., tomorrow, there is a bus from "Rust Rathaus" at 7:48 arriving at "Ringsheim Bahnhof" at 7:56.

There are also buses to other train stations in the area where you might be able to board your train.

You can also search on [bahn.de](https://www.bahn.com/en).

Comment: Aside: if the train is at 8:20, a peak travel time, and the station is unfamiliar, you should already be there before 8.00.

Comment: The stations in that area (Ringsheim and Herbolzheim) only have 2 tracks, so not as complicated to navigate as other bigger stations.

Comment: Use the DB app, it is in english and works in the whole country

Answer (score 3):

There is a taxi company, that serves Rust, however their website is only in german: https://www.taxi700.de/
They claim to be available 24/7, and they have a considerable fleet. Given that Europa-Park is a well known tourist destination, i think the company should be quite reliable.
You can order online on their website as well, or you can use the "taxi.de" app (https://www.taxi.de/app-anwendung/), but i'm not sure if that app is localized to other languages.